# How to change the textview of the fragment from PagerAdapter class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new.I have a problem when trying to set the text of the fragment using my pageradapter.

The Fragment layout just have 1 TextView .

```
public class Cau1 extends Fragment {

    public TextView texview1;
    public static String texthere = null;
    public Cau1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);
        texview1 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        texview1.setText(texthere);
        return rootView;
    }
```

My adapter is :

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(arg0 == 0)
        {
            fragment = new Cau1();
            Cau1.texthere = "This is page 1";

        }
        if(arg0 == 1)
        {
            fragment = new Cau1();
            Cau1.texthere = "This is page 2";

        }
        if(arg0 == 2)
        {
            fragment = new Cau1();
            Cau1.texthere = "This is page 3";

        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }
```

It has 3 pages . Its result is:

First page: This is page 1

Second page : This is page 2

Third page : This is page 3

Please help me . Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Fragment have a static method that returns itself

```
public class Cau1 extends Fragment {

    public TextView texview1;
    public int pageNumber;
    public Cau1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    static Cau1 newInstance(int pageNumber) {
        Cau1 f = new Cau1();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", pageNumber);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt("num");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);
        texview1 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        texview1.setText("Page " + String.valueOf(pageNumber));
        return rootView;
    }
```

and replace your FragmentPagerAdapter getItem() with

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    return Cau1.newInstance(arg0+1);
}
```